# In Eclipse, why does "Build Automatically" get mysteriously disabled?

Tags: eclipse

I'm running Eclipse Europa (3.3).  I leave the "Build Automatically" setting, under the Project menu, on all the time.  Once in awhile my code isn't compiling, and I puzzle over it and then pull down the Project menu ... lo and behold, it's not set anymore.  What gives?  Is this a bug, or is there something else I'm doing that could cause it?

Edit:  I am running the regular Java developer installation, plus Subversive and its connectors, Jetty Launcher, and I believe no other plugins.  Other people at my workplace have had the same problem.

Edit:  I am still having this problem once in a blue moon, only now I'm using Eclipse Galileo (3.5) for Windows.  I haven't had this problem in Galileo for OS X, neither in Cocoa nor Carbon, but I have not used that for as long.

Comment: For us newbies, that Eclipse option is in **Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build automatically**.

Comment: @JohnK it's also on Project > Build Automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have eclipse right here to test and make sure but here is an idea.

Is any of the project or even workspace file in SVN ? if they are and they were uploaded with auto build disabled that might explain it

You update and overwrite your settings. This doesn't become apparent until you restart eclipse. this would also explain why other people at your workplace experienc this. it would even explain why some don't : thay are the ones who are careful what they update and don't allow eclipse to overwrite their own settings plus the ones who actually prefer to have autobuild disabled :)

Answer (score 8):

With Eclipise Mars.1 (4.5.1), Oomph may be the culprit.  Eclipse Oomph supports automatically disabling Build Automatically with entries in

On Windows
%USERPROFILE%\.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.setup\setups\user.setup

If you want to disable this Oomph behavior try deleting the following setting

"Eclipse->Navigate Menu-> Open Setup menu entry-> Open User menu entry", a Preference Task under "User Preferences -> org.eclipse.core.resources -> description.autobuilding"

I learned about this setting by posting to the Oomph Eclipse Community Forum on Feb 8th, 2016.  I posted a question titled "Oomph Defect? Build Automatically Keeps Getting Disabled".  Ed Marks replied the same day with details about Oomph's support for managing the Eclipse "Build Automatically" setting.
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1722751/#msg_1722751

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks mate (y)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and when I looked at the Source tab under Java Build Path (under the menu Project > Properties ) there were some source directories that didn't exist anymore (marked with a red X). After I deleted them, compilation worked fine and all new .class files are under the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Strange.  Is there perhaps a plugin installed that turns this off without your knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some conflicting shortcut. For example, some duplicated shortcut may be toggling it.

Answer (score 1):

I am running 3.4 and I also have this mysterious behavior. I had it in 3.3 as well. I use CVS not SVN. Does not seem to follow a pattern just once in a while it gets switched off and then weird confusing stuff happens until I remember to check it and switch it back on.   I am almost to the point where I want to write a plugin to always turn it on when eclipse loads.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Google Plugin for Eclipse, 'Google App Engine for Android' is also installed.

For me, I uninstalled 'Google App Engine for Android', which I didn't need, and solved this problem.