# Why does Eclipes 3.4.0 apparently untick "Build automatically"?

Tags: eclipse

I have a old workspace in Eclipse 3.4.0 that I use for plugin development. I am experiencing a problem which I think is a bug in this version. In the workbench menu bar (Project->Build automatically) , I ticked "Build automatically",  but each time my workspace starts, it gets unticked. Why?

Comment: @Michael yes now it looks more appealing.

Comment: When you close eclipse do you find any errors in the log file? Or do you cancel the "workspace compression" maybe?

Comment: no i dont have any error and not doing any thing as you describe above.

Comment: It's possible a plug-in that you've installed is toggling this itself.  Some (bad) plug-ins think nothing of altering the preferences of other plug-ins.  What exactly is installed, and does it still happen with the current version, 3.7.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115770/in-eclipse-why-does-build-automatically-get-mysteriously-disabled?rq=1) gives a possible answer: If you put your workspace metadata under version control (instead of only the workspace contents), you might be updating the workspace meta data wrongly using the version control system (either inside or outside of Eclipse).